# How to load data from AWS S3 to Snowflake Internal Stage

Tags: database-migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are trying to take our data from an AWS S3 (external stage) and load it into a Snowflake internal stage. Snowflake should act as our data lake, and can reduce the amount of storage we use from AWS. Is there any built in functionality that can transfer data from external stage --> internal stage?

The goal is to load the data into the internal Snowflake stage and subsequently delete the data from AWS. We want Snowflake to be the data lake.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean `internal stage`?

If you are planning to load into Snowflake tables, your scenario is perfect use case for Snowpipe, for more info [Automating Snowpipe for Amazon S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#automating-snowpipe-for-amazon-s3)

Comment: I do plan on using Snowpipe. The question that was asked is can we store the raw data in Snowflake to use Snowflake as a data lake and move the storage off of S3. We want to reduce S3 usage.

My plan, and what I learned in the tutorials, is to create a RAW_INGEST table to load in data, and then do the transformation into a final table when needed. I know it seems like a strange request, but it was what was asked of me.

Comment: Yes. You can move your data into Snowflake "as is". The approach you described above is common and called `ELT` I have the same implemented in our Snowflake environment

Comment: So you suggest moving the data "as is" into a raw table, correct? This is the approach I have been recommending but higher ups are inquiring about how to use Snowflake as the data lake.

Comment: @Dave how best you move and handle the data will depend on what type of data it is - is it tabular, semi-structured or unstructured?

Comment: @Hotchips CSV (structured) data

Answer (score 1):

An internal stage would just be a different S3 bucket utilized by Snowflake.  So it's not really "reducing" the amount of storage, just changing its location.  If you still wanted to do this, you could GET from your external stage and PUT to the internal stage.  Or you could just load from the external stage to your tables in Snowflake via any of the available methods.

Comment: The goal is just to get the storage off of S3 and into Snowflake to use Snowflake as the data lake. With that in consideration, would you still recommend GET from S3 --> PUT into internal stage? I can't see why this would be better than just creating a `RAW_INGEST` table to hold all of the raw data. Once the data is in Snowflake I am going to auto-delete off of S3.

Comment: Also for clarification, the GET documentation states the data must come from an internal stage. The S3 bucket stage is technically an external stage.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to stop thinking that a "data lake" means a bunch of raw data files stored in a cloud bucket somewhere.  That's the 2010 version of a data lake.
In Snowflake, you can load the raw data into tables that mirror those files (either structured column-by-column, or semi-structured JSON,XML,Parquet...).  Think of these tables as your "raw" zone. With Streams and Tasks, you can automate the curation of the data in the raw zone into a second set of tables - the "curated" zone.  Another set of Streams/Tasks might go another step and pre-aggregate the curated data into an "aggregated" zone.  The design of the workflows is up to you.
The cloud storage just becomes a "landing area" for raw extracted data, and can be deleted after ingestion into Snowflake.  You now have a single platform for your raw data, curated data, and aggregated data. Hook up a data governance tool like Alation or Collibra to maintain the lineage of the data through its journey.

-Paul-